# advice on database design

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a database for my website. I have a schema here : [enrolin.in/download.png](http://enrolin.in/download.png)
**Introduction to website:**
It collects data from students on behalf of colleges.
Now what I have done in database is that I have created a UDT-where data that is fixed to a student is stored. and CST-where data that can change with every new course is stored.
I am very new to database design, so please have a look at the database design and advice me where i can improve. I want it to be perfect so that there are no complications/limitations with database in future
**NOTES:**
There is not just for one college. It is like a platform where different colleges can add their courses. Every college has different courses with different subjects etc. There can be many CST's, may be a separate CST for every new course. Plus I am not sure about the way I am storing course data , I mean CST and UDT. Every college will have access to the data of students which have applied for a course under that college and every student will have access to data to his previously filled form data,status etc.

Thanks in advance. If anything is unclear, please ask in comments.

Update : -- tables
-- Table CST

```
CREATE TABLE CST (
    cst_id int    NOT NULL ,
    rollno int    NOT NULL ,
    semester int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT CST_pk PRIMARY KEY (cst_id)
);
```

-- Table UDT

```
CREATE TABLE UDT (
    udt_id int    NOT NULL ,
    id int    NOT NULL ,
    name varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    gender varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    fatherame varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    mothername varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    dob date    NOT NULL ,
    signature binary(255)    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT UDT_pk PRIMARY KEY (udt_id)
);
```

-- Table address

```
CREATE TABLE address (
    address_id int    NOT NULL ,
    id int    NOT NULL ,
    add_name varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    add_street varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    city varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    state varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    country varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    pin int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT address_pk PRIMARY KEY (address_id)
);
```

-- Table courses

```
CREATE TABLE courses (
    course_id int    NOT NULL ,
    course_name varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT courses_pk PRIMARY KEY (course_id)
);
```

-- Table phones

```
CREATE TABLE phones (
    phone_id int    NOT NULL ,
    id int    NOT NULL ,
    phone int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT phones_pk PRIMARY KEY (phone_id)
);
```

-- Table photos

```
CREATE TABLE photos (
    photo_id int    NOT NULL ,
    id int    NOT NULL ,
    photo binary(255)    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT photos_pk PRIMARY KEY (photo_id)
);
```

-- Table sub_trans

```
CREATE TABLE sub_trans (
    sub_trans_id int    NOT NULL ,
    transactions_t_id int    NOT NULL ,
    subjects_sub_id int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT sub_trans_pk PRIMARY KEY (sub_trans_id)
);
```

-- Table subjects

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
    sub_id int    NOT NULL ,
    course_id int    NOT NULL ,
    subjectname varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT subjects_pk PRIMARY KEY (sub_id)
);
```

-- Table transactions

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    t_id int    NOT NULL ,
    id int    NOT NULL ,
    course_id int    NOT NULL ,
    p_status int    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    phones_phone_id int    NOT NULL ,
    UDT_udt_id int    NOT NULL ,
    photos_photo_id int    NOT NULL ,
    address_address_id int    NOT NULL ,
    CST_cst_id int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT transactions_pk PRIMARY KEY (t_id)
);
```

-- Table users

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int    NOT NULL ,
    name varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    email varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    password int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

`

Comment: Make it perfect ok. Make it not complicated?

Comment: Hello Drew, Thanks even I feel its complicated, how can I improve it? any suggestions?

Comment: Can you render it as text. As in `show create table xxx` for each

Comment: :/ I am confused. It will be very difficult

Comment: Ok u can't run commands against the mysql db?

Comment: yes I can . They run fine right now. But I am just worried that I should not face any complications in future. I feel the subject and course section of database is limited in someway and may hit a roadblock later

Comment: Run the cmd i said above

Comment: okay here it is : in update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UDT**:

Typo fathername. UDT has an FK to what? Users? Slim down the varchar size in UDT. Sure you want a single column for name? Ok, at least document that you chose to not have more than 2 parents. Otherwise you need another table.

**Users**:

Passwords run thru a hash function won't be ints and user needs a Salt for optimal security. Imho.

**awaiting more clarification below**

There is zero purpose of UDT and users both existing. Pick one, pickup lost fields from one you are ditching.

Even hypothetically if it wasn't 1:1 `name` would denomalize the database.

**phones**:

Your columns for phones need to be described. Also can a user have more than 1 phone (if so, phoneType varchar(10)  or int code? ) 
Also I would go like varchar(30) on phone `value` not an int.

**Addresses**:

Same deal as phones. Can a user have more than one? PostalCode pin should be varchar

**Transactions**:

This seems to be the hub of your schema. All of your transactions hinge on FKs to data that *may* have subsequently changed. **I see RISK in that.** Older transaction could get skewed results for lookups. There are easy ways to fix this issue if you even see it as one. Same goes for courses. What if History 101's id stays the same but next semester that id is Early Roman Empire? Just things to think about.

Lastly the documented tables have no FK relationships shown.

Comment: I have updated the question drew. Is it what you were asking for?

Comment: sure passwords can be an int. depends on how passwords are hashed/stored :p but it would probably impose a limit of 2147483647 different passwords nontheless

Comment: UDT table has a fk from users that recognizes whose details are these by matching them to users table.

Comment: so UDT is always 1:1 to users table? If so why have it? Plus you denormalize the database with `name`

Comment: Oh... I get your point. Yes UDT is 1:1, may be I should merge it back into users. And `name` denormalizes database? Okay I think there are two names one in users and one in UDT. I will fix it. Thanks Drew.

Comment: is there any thing that can go wrong? I mean while performing database search / editing data / viewing data etc

Comment: Things often go wrong. Keep posting schema changes as text. I'll be here.